# Thymeleaf not recognizing CSS files

Tags: css, thymeleaf

I am trying to link a CSS stylesheet using Thymeleaf html. When I run the application and test online no styling is being applied.

Below is my html code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Homepage</title>
    <link th:href="@{/css/main.css}" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body class="custom-bg">

<nav>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a th:href="@{/admin/homepage}">
                Home
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a th:href="@{/welcome}">
                Page 1
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a th:href="@{/admin/new/employees}">
                Create New Employee
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <form th:action="@{/logout}" method="post" >
                <button type="submit">Logout</button>
            </form>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>

<h1>Admin homepage</h1>
<h2>Welcome,</h2>
<h3 th:text="${employee.getFirstName()} + ' ' + ${employee.getLastName()}">Name</h3>

</body>
</html>
```

This is my CSS file

```
* {
    color: aqua;
}

.custom-bg {
    background-color: deeppink;
}

body {
    background-color: deeppink;
}
```

Image of my file structure
[Project file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJzrC.png)

I have researched online and from thymeleaf documentation, I am seeing the default file path/structure is the same as mine and css files should be recognized and be able to be called using the below link href.

```html
<link th:href="@{/css/main.css}" rel="stylesheet">
```

However when I use this link href (below), the IDE intelliSense is picking up that there is a file there, but when I run the application there is no styling being applied.

```html
<link th:href="@{../static/css/main.css}" rel="stylesheet">
```

I also saw that spring security could be causing issues. So I added file path to my filter chain configuration file.

```
 @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> {
            auth.requestMatchers("/admin/**")
                    .hasAuthority("ADMIN");
            auth.requestMatchers("/manager/**")
                    .hasAuthority("MANAGER");
            auth.requestMatchers("/employee/**")
                    .hasAuthority("EMPLOYEE");
            auth.requestMatchers("employees")
                    .hasAnyAuthority("MANAGER", "EMPLOYEE");
            auth.requestMatchers("/css/**")
                            .permitAll();
            auth.requestMatchers("/js/**")
                    .permitAll();
            auth.requestMatchers("/images/**")
                    .permitAll();
            auth.anyRequest().authenticated();
        });

        http.httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults());

        http.formLogin()
                .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
                .successHandler(loginSuccessHandler)
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID");

        http.csrf((AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable));

        return http.build();
    }
```

Lastly, when I load the webpage, the console gives me this error. I provided both versions, depending on which link href I used. (provided above).
Do I need to map a GET request in the controller to access the CSS file?

```
2023-09-29T14:48:19.939+01:00  WARN 4772 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound             : No mapping for GET /static/css/main.css
```

```
2023-09-29T14:59:52.447+01:00  WARN 14708 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound             : No mapping for GET /css/main.css
```

EDIT
I wanted to show my whole configuration class in case something was causing an issue that I couldn't see.

```
 package com.sparta.tma.config;

import com.sparta.tma.services.LoginSuccessHandler;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.config.Customizer;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.AbstractHttpConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;

@Configuration
@AllArgsConstructor
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableWebMvc
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private LoginSuccessHandler loginSuccessHandler;

    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> {
            auth.requestMatchers("/admin/**")
                    .hasAuthority("ADMIN");
            auth.requestMatchers("/manager/**")
                    .hasAuthority("MANAGER");
            auth.requestMatchers("/employee/**")
                    .hasAuthority("EMPLOYEE");
            auth.requestMatchers("employees")
                    .hasAnyAuthority("MANAGER", "EMPLOYEE");
            auth.requestMatchers("/css/**")
                            .permitAll();
            auth.requestMatchers("/static/**")
                    .permitAll();
            auth.requestMatchers("/resources/**")
                    .permitAll();
            auth.anyRequest().authenticated();
        });

        http.httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults());

        http.formLogin()
                .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
                .successHandler(loginSuccessHandler) 
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID");

        http.csrf((AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable));

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authManager(UserDetailsService detailsService) {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider provider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        provider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        provider.setUserDetailsService(detailsService);

        return new ProviderManager(provider);
    }
}
```

**UPDATE-SOLVED**

The following controller loads css files with the correct content type.

```
@GetMapping(value = "/css/{fileName:.+}", produces = "text/css")
    public ResponseEntity<Resource> getCssFile(@PathVariable String fileName) {
        // Construct the path to the CSS file based on the provided file name
        String cssFilePath = "static/css/" + fileName;

        // Load the CSS file as a resource from the classpath
        Resource resource = new ClassPathResource(cssFilePath);

        // Return a ResponseEntity with the CSS file
        return ResponseEntity.ok()
            .header("Content-Disposition", "inline")
            .body(resource);
    }
```

Comment: `th:href="@{/css/main.css}"` is what you should be using. Could it be that you have other configuration in your project you are not telling us about in your question? Maybe start with a small project that only has Thymeleaf and Spring MVC without any security for example?

Comment: @WimDeblauwe I have tried using th:href="@{/css/main.css}" but it still doesn't work. I don't have any other configurations other than a couple of beans which I will update in the config section now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you open the CSS file in the browser, what happens? 404 or redirection to a page of your application?

I also had a few challenges and solved it this way.

The path of the CSS file is in my project: /src/main/resources/static/main.css

**Template**

```html
<link th:href="@{/static/main.css}" rel="stylesheet" />
```

**application.properties**

```
spring.mvc.static-path-pattern=/static/**
```

**InterceptorsConfig**

```java
@Configuration
public class InterceptorsConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
   
    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addPathPatterns("/**")
                .excludePathPatterns("/static/**");
    }

}
```

Comment: I didn't implement this in the same way, I tried, but addPathPatterns were not working well with InterceptorRegistry, I tried to implement it with InterceptorRegistration but it wouldnt take a string as a parameter and I honestly have never seen this before and didn't understand it. 

However your solution got me researching and I found a similar approach using controllers. It seems every thing in my static folder is being recognized as json content type, even my images!

Comment: Also to answer your question and for anyone else with this issue, I was getting a 404 on the web browser, content type was set as application/json along with an error in the web console saying _Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:8080/admin/static/css/register.css' because its MIME type ('application/json') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled._

Comment: How are the static files delivered now? With a 404, the path cannot be resolved. Do you deliver the files via controller? Since it may be that all files are application/json. The MimeType must then be set individually for each file type. However, I would not deliver static files via a controller.

Comment: Right now it's being handled by the controller. Yes I had to set each type individually especially for the image types! Before that static files were just being handled by spring's default (I think MVC) but there seems to be a bad config somewhere with returning every thing as json. Until now, the only controllers I had were @Controller classes handling endpoints to the webpages. I feel like I just stuck a bandage over it and would love to actually fix the underlying issue that is causing it

Comment: You can download [here](https://github.com/alaugks/spring-messagesource-xliff-example-spring-boot) an example that works without a controller here.

Comment: Thanks for that, I took a look and implemented this based on the example and everything looks good but the interceptor is never invoked. I will continue to look into it.  Thanks again!