Accessing static elements with Spring Boot 3.2.5 and security settings
I can't access the static elements on a HTML page, from a Spring Boot 3.2.5 application, with this security settings:
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    
    http
        .csrf(csrf -> csrf
            .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())
            .ignoringRequestMatchers("/redsys/**")
        )
        .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize                        
            .requestMatchers("/images/**", "/js**", "/css/**", "/webjars/**").permitAll()  
            .requestMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("USER")
            .requestMatchers("/backstage/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
            .requestMatchers("/actuator/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
            .anyRequest().permitAll()
        )
        .formLogin(formLogin -> formLogin
            .loginPage("/login").permitAll()
            .loginProcessingUrl("/perform_login")    
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/admin")
            .failureUrl("/login?error=true")    
        )
        .logout(logOut -> logOut
            .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
        )
        .sessionManagement(session -> session
            .maximumSessions(5).expiredUrl("/login?logout")
        );
                    
    return http.build();
}

This is the HTML page:


<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/images/rentalwebs50.png"/>
        <meta name="_csrf" th:content="${_csrf.token}"/>
    <meta name="_csrf_header" th:content="${_csrf.headerName}"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Login</h1>
        <form name='f' action="login" method='POST'>
           <table>
               <tr>
                  <td>User:</td>
                  <td><input type='text' name='username' value=''></td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td>Password:</td>
                  <td><input type='password' name='password' /></td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td><input id="submitButton" name="submit" type="submit" value="submit" /></td>
               </tr>
            </table>
         </form>
         <img scr="/images/rentalwebs50.png" alt="testing static resources"></img>
   </body>
   <footer>
       <script src="/js/CsrfToken.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
   </footer>
</html>



Those are the static resources, that can't be accessed, with its path into the file structure:

/src/main/resources/static/images/rentalwebs50.png
/src/main/resources/static/js/CsrfToken.js"

Finally, the browser arises this error for the javascript file:
CsrfToken.js: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()

Please take a look at this question and my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77202560/thymeleaf-not-recognizing-css-files/

The problem was that at the WebMvcConfigurer implementation, there was the @EnableWebMvc annotation.
@EnableWebMvc disables Spring Boot's autoconfiguration for MVC, therefore the standard  path for static resources (/src/main/resources/static/), didn't work, unless it was manually configured into the properties file.
